# How can I call dos commands in Ruby and get the results?

Tags: windows, ruby

There is a command I want to call that returns a string, I want to call this command while inside a ruby script, and have access to the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming by command you mean an OS command.

```
# this will execute ls and assign the dir listing to the variable
dir_list = `ls` 
os_user  = `whoami`
```

Comment: KandadaBoggu, it's you! You beat me to it! (+1)

Comment: @smotchkkiss Low hanging fruit :-). Damn this game is addictive.

Answer (score 0):

you have the method `Kernel#system` too http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005971

```
system "dir"
```